# Monitor worker process with nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I am working on setting up Nagios monitoring. I was able to setup and monitor the system processes. Now, I am working on setting up monitoring for custom running processes.

We are having python worker process running with identifier. Each process is having it's separate pid file (worker_1.pid, worker_2.pid)

```
root      3642     1  3 Jan24 ?        08:22:36 /usr/bin/python /test/worker.py -i 1 
root      345     1  3 Jan24 ?        08:22:36 /usr/bin/python /test/worker.py -i 2
```

I am not sure which option I have to use of check_procs to monitor these processes separately?

```
root@instance:/etc/nagios# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -C python -a worker
PROCS OK: 2 processes with command name 'python', args 'worker'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use option -a as you used in your example, but like this:

```
root@nagios:/etc/nagios3/conf.d# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -C mysqld -a "--basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql"
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'mysqld', args '--basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql'
```

So in your case it would be:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -C python -a "/test/worker.py -i 1"
```

And then it should match only one process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's working for me. Just curious, is this best possible solution to do string match. Is there any other way (using pid) for achieve this?

Comment: Plugin check_procs (which is part of nagios-plugins package) has only option for checking arguments (option -a) or checking parent PID of the 
running process (option -p). But it has no option for checking PID of the process. You can go through this site of plugins 
(http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins) and maybe you will find some other plugin which will be able to check process by its PID.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Thanks Mike for formatting my question.

Comment: Is there anything else you would like to know, or it is solved?